# Why can't I mention more than one person in a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

Why is mentioning 2, 3, ... users (by `@user`) in one comment not allowed?

What's the bad thing could happen if Stack Overflow allows it? I didn't understand.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to?  Comments aren't meant to be around for very long and they could easily disappear at the drop of a hat.

Comment: Well, why not go further and allow a bulk mailing list?  (that's code for NO).

Comment: @Makoto There are multiple users confused in comments below an answer. I would like to tag them all when I provide an answering comment.

Comment: @Qwerty:  That exceeds the scope of comments.  If you suddenly feel compelled to talk to *everyone* in a comments section, you're not on Stack Overflow - you're on a forum.  And Stack Overflow is very much *not* a forum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comments will be used to **talk with one person to clarify something**, which the person posted on your question/answer.

Otherwise, SO users would abuse the comment section to bring attention to their Q&A, which would most likely be perceived as negative.

Example:

> @abdulla @Robert_Harvey @DMaster, please check my question

We also can't ping mods. Please also read: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: Are you sure you can't ping mods, even if they posted/commented in the question?

Comment: So does it work to ping multiple people as in your example or not?

Comment: @Qwerty You can't ping multiple people. Address one at a time to clarify or ask something

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Sure, I know. I was just confused by your Answer. It is worded in such a way that suggests that *"users might use a single comment to call everyone"*. Anyway it would be so much easier if it worked. I was answering a concern where all the commenters literally had the same question. One of them even literally said *"I second this, we need to wait for some expert to step in."*.

Answer (score 6):

Comments have only two sanctioned purposes: to clarify a post, or to ask for clarification.  So ask yourself: how would talking to two people at the same time advance these purposes?

There are plenty of unsanctioned uses, however.  It's just that we don't feel the need to encourage those uses.

Comment: We can't stop you from using your car to drive thumbtacks into corkboard, but we do our best not to make it so easy as to encourage that sort of thing.

Comment: @TimPost: Well, I already determined when to use the bottle and when the old shoe, but I wasn't aware that using my car might be a viable alternative. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Or basically:  StackOverflow is still in denial about the actual value and use of comments, and are actively making the site worse by keeping their head in the ground.

Comment: "how would talking to two people at the same time advance these purposes?" For example, if two different users asked for clarification in a comment section, I might want to do just a single comment to answer both and notify them both by tagging them. Otherwise what should I do? Do two separate, identical, comments each one tagging one user? [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466993/minimize-crossings-in-a-radial-graph-networkx-graphviz?noredirect=1#comment108745442_61466993)